# d3.js: how to conditionally render a curve?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got a function that draws a curve through dots I give as argument, as follows:

```
var data = [
  // stage 1-9, intensity %, draw disk
  {x:1, y:  0, point:true},
  {x:4, y: 30, point:true},
  {x:5, y: 70, point:true},
  {x:6, y:100, point:true},
  {x:7, y: 90, point:true},
  {x:8, y: 40, point:true},
  {x:9, y: 10, point:false}
];
```

I'd like to handle the point members that tells whether or not to draw an additional spot.

How to do that?

The function that draws the curve as it is per today:

```
function curveChart(data) {

    for (i in data) {
        data[i].y = 5.5*data[i].y/100;  // normalize
        data[i].id = i;
    }

    var margin  = {top: 10, right: 190, bottom: 275, left: 35},
        width   = 915 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height  = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear() //.time.scale()
        .domain([1, 9])     // 9 stages
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 6])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("monotone")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

    var svg = d3.select(".curveChart").append("svg")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);

    var n = 1;
                svg.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "dot")
                    .attr("cx", line.x())
                    .attr("cy", line.y())
                    .attr("r", 2)
                    .attr("bubbleid", function(d){return d.id; })
                    .transition(1000)
                    .duration(800)
                    .attr("r", 10);

    svg.selectAll("circle").on("click", function(){

        d3.selectAll(".active").classed("active", false);
        d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

        var id = $(this).attr('bubbleid');
        console.log("clicked on "+$(this).attr('bubbleid'));

        $(".bubble").removeClass("show");
        $("#bubble"+id).addClass("show");

        d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(400)
            .attr('r', 25)
            .transition()
            .duration(400)
                .attr('r', 10)
                ;
    });
}
```

The fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/R44cB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to filter the data before passing it to `.data()`, retaining only the elements where `point` is true:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data.filter(function(d) { return d.point; }))
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R44cB/4/).